# Lego NXT / Groovy Support

Tags: ros, nxt, ros-groovy, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to learn ROS.  I have Lego NXT, so I figure this is a good place to start.  The NXT page recommends an older version of ROS (diamondback), but I have install issues on OS X Mountain Lion.  Is there any plan to update for Groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51265/lego-nxt-/-groovy-support/) by [seanstocktonclark](https://answers.ros.org/users/3875/seanstocktonclark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-12-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

same question dont know osx
http://answers.ros.org/question/52836/lego-nxt-ros-working-on-groovy-galapagos/?comment=69874#comment-69874

---

Originally posted by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) with karma: 181 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0